# Validation for Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dropdowns with same list populated from database . I want to validate  where dropdown 1 value is not same as dropdown 2 . 
Thanks
SmartDev

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stay in the asp.net world use a [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx) using [`Operator="NotEqual"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.operator(v=VS.90).aspx) like this:

```
  <asp:CompareValidator id="Compare1" runat="server"
       ControlToValidate="DropDown1" 
       ControlToCompare="DropDown1"
       EnableClientScript="True"
       Operator="NotEqual"
       ErrorMessage="Duplicate selection detected"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick .i tried this but its not working on my side ..my code
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CVCtAhk" runat="server" ControlToCompare="DdlsecondaryresaonCTAhk"
                    ControlToValidate="DdlPrimaryreasonCTAhk" ErrorMessage="Primary reason and secondary reason cannot be same"
                    Operator="NotEqual" ValidationGroup="VGCTAhk">*</asp:CompareValidator>

Comment: @SmartDev - What's it doing or rather, not doing?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net comes with a whole suite of validator controls.  A quick look at them is all you really need to find out how to do this.

```
<asp:CompareValidator id="valCompare" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="dropdown1" 
    ControlToCompare="dropdown2"
    Operator="NotEqual"
    ErrorMessage="* You must enter different values into the dropdownboxes"
    Display="dynamic">*
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ddl1.SelectedValue != ddl2.SelectedValue)
{
    //different
}
else
{
    //same
}
```

Comment: Thanks Durilai ..this is also working ,now i have a choice i can use  anything .